# SOAP client using perl - WSDL URL is available

Tags: xml, powershell, perl, web-services, soap

I have a powershell script which will make a soap call, and perform the following operations:
1.Connects to the server hosting the WSDL (called cell in application terminology)
2.Creates an event(alert) in it.
3.Disconnects from the server hosting the WSDL(called cell in application terminology)
I want to create perl version of this script.. which does the same exact operations,Please help me with functions and examples. or if possible by rewriting the below script in perl.
Thank you so much in advance:

the PS script is as below:

===============================================================================

```
$severity = "MAJOR"

$msg = "Test event from Powershell"
$cellname = "mycell"

$url = "http://iiwshostname:9080/imws/services/ImpactManager/"
$headers = @{ "SOAPAction" = "Connect"}
$soap = [xml]@"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:imap="http://blueprint.bmc.com/ImapiElems">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <imap:Connect>
         <imap:userName>admin</imap:userName>
         <imap:password>admin</imap:password>
         <imap:imname>$cellname</imap:imname>
         <imap:bufferType>BMCII_BUFFER_MODE_DEFAULT</imap:bufferType>
      </imap:Connect>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@
[xml]$ret = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $soap -Headers $headers
$connectionId = $ret.GetElementsByTagName("imap:connectionId").'#text'

$headers = @{ "SOAPAction" = "SendEvent"}
$soap = [xml]@"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:imap="http://blueprint.bmc.com/ImapiElems" xmlns:bas="http://blueprint.bmc.com/BasicTypes" xmlns:even="http://blueprint.bmc.com/Event">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <imap:SendEvent>
         <imap:connection>$connectionId</imap:connection>
         <imap:message>    
            <bas:NameValue_element>    
               <bas:name>msg</bas:name>    
               <bas:value>    
                  <bas:string_value>$msg</bas:string_value>    
               </bas:value>    
               <bas:value_type>STRING</bas:value_type>    
            </bas:NameValue_element>    
            <bas:NameValue_element>    
               <bas:name>severity</bas:name>    
               <bas:value>    
                  <bas:string_alue>$severity</bas:string_value>    
               </bas:value>   
               <bas:value_type>STRING</bas:value_type>    
            </bas:NameValue_element>              
            <even:subject></even:subject>    
         </imap:message>    
         <imap:timeout>60</imap:timeout>    
         <imap:messageClass>EVENT</imap:messageClass>    
         <imap:messageType>MSG_TYPE_NEW_EVENT</imap:messageType>    
      </imap:SendEvent>    
   </soapenv:Body>    
</soapenv:Envelope>    
"@    
[xml]$ret = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $soap -Headers $headers    

$mc_ueid = $ret.GetElementsByTagName("imap:response").'#text'    

$headers = @{ "SOAPAction" = "Disconnect"}    
$soap = [xml]@"    
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soapenvelope/" xmlns:imap="http://blueprint.bmc.com/ImapiElems">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <imap:Disconnect>
             <imap:connection>$connectionId</imap:connection>
             <imap:deleteBuffer>No</imap:deleteBuffer>    
      </imap:Disconnect>    
   </soapenv:Body>    
</soapenv:Envelope>    
"@    
$ret = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $soap -Headers $headers    

write-host $mc_ueid
```

===============================================================================

Comment: Here is the source of the above PS script 
https://communities.bmc.com/thread/92279

but i want to modify and enhance this script for my own use. 
so i want to understand which functions to use. and how? in perl ' SOAP::lite module is the best one use '  is what is got from research.

Comment: I don't know what research you got that from, but [XML::Compile::SOAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::SOAP) is vastly recommended over the horrible SOAP::Lite, and much better supported by the author.

Comment: @Grinnz Thanks a lot., But I want to know the equivalent function of  -----[xml]$ret = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Body $soap -Headers $headers--------- this in perl, I will  go through the module you mentioned 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Grinnz : please don’t use SOAP::Lite, it’s ugly. The de facto standard to run SOAP operations over HTTP in Perl is [XML::Compile::SOAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::SOAP), which is quite complete, well maintained and thoroughly documented. However it can be a little complicated to get your head around it, due to the inherent complexity of the SOAP protocol. The following explanation should get you started.

Before all you have to load the modules :

```
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
```

Then the first step is to create a WSDL object and load the WSDL file :

```
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new;
$wsdl->addWSDL($wsdl_file);
```

If your WSDL file depends on some XSD files, then you have to load them first, before the WSDL, by calling :

```
$wsdl->importDefinitions($xsd_file);
```

Please note that for security reasons, XML::Compile will never try to load online resources ; you have to download them manually and then load them from disk.

The second step is to compile the object. This will actually create persistent code references in the object, that you can invoke repeatedly afterwards to perform operations. You pass the url of the target service as an argument to the compiler. For example, the following call compiles all available operations :

```
$wsdl->compileCalls( address => $url);
```

At compile time, you also have the possibility of passing your own HTTP transport object instead of relying on XML::Compile defaults. This is useful when you want fine-grained control on the transport layer (like setting a HTTP proxy, ...). For example with LWP::UserAgent :

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( show_progress => 1 );
$wsdl->compileCalls( address => $self->url, user_agent => $ua );
```

Now you are ready to invoke the webservice. You pass the name of the operation and a data structure, as follows :

```
my ( $answer, $trace ) = $wsdl->call( $ope, $data );
```

If anything goes wrong, the call dies. On success, it returns a Perl data structure that represents the parsed response. That’s it !

XML::Compile provides a lot of useful introspection and debugging methods. For example, after compilation, you can print the list all available operations with :

```
$wsdl->printIndex;
```

To display the details of the input data structure of a given operation :

```
$wsdl->explain( $ope, PERL => "INPUT", recurse => 1 );
```

After an operation was executed, the trace object can be used to obtain many internal details about how things happened, for example :

```
$trace->printRequest;
$trace->printResponse;
$trace->printTimings;
```

Comment: Let me try to write the above code in perl and try to execute. And seek ur help if I still don't get it.. again thanks for the help.!!

Comment: Hi @GMB,
i have the wsdl url : http://hostname:9080/imws/services/ImpactManager?wsdl
if i enter this in the browser i am able to see the tree structure of definitions in xml format., but now how do i download this as file ? how do i know if there is dependency on xsd files ? how to download them too?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::WSDL11 
i found the functions you mentioned here

Comment: @kaushikkm : just copy the content you see in the browser and paste it in a local file. For XSD you have to look at the content and search for « xsd » tags pointing at external resources

Comment: okey i can copy and past it into a file.what extention should i save it with  ?

Comment: i can also see the xsd source which it is pointing to.
so i should copy paste the content of those 4 xsd into 4 different files and load it with 4 different commands like `$wsdl->importDefinitions($xsd_file);` ?
what should be the extention of xsd files ?

Comment: Yes that’s what you need to do. Extension does not matter, but usually « .xsd » is the standard

Comment: `$wsdl->compileCalls( address => $self->url);`
$wsdl - is an object we created; compileCalls is a method; address is a key word ?
$self->url - indicate what ?
in this url should be replaced with my wsdl url ? $self is a variable ?

i am a complete beginner to use modules in perl and unable to find the same syntax you mentioned in the doc.. so all these questions .. please bare with me.. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Sorry ! That’s just a string that contains the URL of the remote service, I updated my answer

Comment: so in my case:
`$url=http://hostname:9080/imws/services/ImpactManager?wsdl;`
`$wsdl->compileCalls( address => $url);`
should work! am i ryt ? this is the url which gives me all definitions when i put it in the browser.

Comment: You want to remove the « ?wsdl » at the end of the url. Basically this should be the same URL that you are using in your original script

Comment: Ok I will modify the URL and try to execute.. actually it was throwing an error(might be because I had removed "wsdl"). Will update u Tomo same time around. Please stay tuned!

Comment: Also I'm using dwim perl. I think I need to download the modules. The error was something related to module, something like "unable to locate /perl/lib/compile". I will clearly update the error too.. by tomo. Again lots of thanks!!

Comment: i changed the URL to original format and tried to execute:
looks like i need to download the module ?
Please help on this:

**Can't locate XML/Compile/SOAP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: E:/myfolder/Dwimperl
/perl/site/lib E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/p
erl/lib .) at scom2ts_dev.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at scom2ts_dev.pl line 4.
Press any key to continue . . .**

I am getting this error -

Comment: Well, yes you need to install all these modules. Basically every module that you `use` must be installed on your system. Suggest you to first install `App::Cpanminus`, then you can run commands `cpanm XML::Compile::SOAP11` and `cpanm XML::Compile::WSDL11`

Comment: Hi @GMB,
As per the below link [https://perlmaven.com/how-to-install-a-perl-module-from-cpan] as client is already configured in dwimperl version for windows,
i tried to run `cpan XML::Compile::SOAP11` but i was unable to install the module.
i tried to download the module from the link [https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::SOAP]
and copy pasted the contents under /lib to the E:\myfolder\Dwimperl\perl\vendor\lib. but still im getting the error :

Comment: Can't locate Log/Report.pm in @INC (@INC contains: E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/
site/lib E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/li
b .) at E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib/XML
/Compile/SOAP.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 2.
propagated at E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/lib/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:/myfolder/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib/XML
/Compile/SOAP11.pm line 13.

Comment: Compilation failed in require at scom2ts_dev.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at scom2ts_dev.pl line 4.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Hi @GMB 
can you please check this post ?
i was able to follow above and now facing issue in parsing the response.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099644/how-to-parse-the-output-of-soap-response-which-is-in-hash-format-of-data-see-be/56100215#56100215