# how to parse the output of SOAP response which is in HASH format of data? see below code for details

Tags: perl, parsing, soap, hash

```
#perl!
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Compile::SOAP;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;
use Data::Dumper;
##my other variables pointing to wsdl and xsd files.
my $url="http://myhost.com:9080/imws/services/ImpactManager/";
my %inargs_connect = (
    "userName"  => "xxxx",
    "password" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "imname"  => "yyyyyyyyyyy",
    "bufferType"  => "abcd"
);

my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new;
$wsdl->addWSDL($wsdl_file);
$wsdl->compileCalls(address =>$url);
my ($answer, $trace) = $wsdl->call( 'Connect', %inargs_connect);
print ($answer);
```

the above code is printing :
HASH(0x47f8b28)

in the last print statement if i use dumper, i get the below response.
`print Dumper($answer);`

```
$VAR1 = {
          'outargs' => {
                         'connectionId' => '1557666855346'
                       }
        };
```

how to parse the required values like,
i need to be able to easily access 'connectionId' and '1557666855346' ?

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.
Thanks,
Kaushik KM.

Answer (score 1):

`$answer` appears to be a hash reference, so you'd access the data using normal dereferencing techniques:

```
my $conn_id = $answer->{outargs}{connectionId};
print "$conn_id\n";
```

Output:

```
1557666855346
```

Comment: perfect. but how do i access the key ? what if i dont know what all the keys that comes from the response ? i want to print all the keys and its values dynamically. Please help

Comment: [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: @ikegami Could you please help me with the code ?
i hope you have understood my problem, In the response from above...
i may get 10 more keys along with `ConnectionID` and its values...

and along with `outargs` we may get multiple hash as well.

so i want to be able to access each of them also print them..
please help with loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %fhash = %{$answer};
my $key = "";
foreach $key (keys %fhash)
{
print "keys are\n \"$key\" its value is (${$answer}{$key}) \n";

    foreach my $key2 (keys %${$answer}{$key})
    {
    print "keys of(${$answer}{$key})\n \"$key2\"\n";
    }
}
```

is not working and is throwing error as follows: 
Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at CreateEvent.pl line 64.
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash or array (not key/value hash slice) at Create
Event.pl line 64, near "}

can someone correct this please.

Comment: This should have been submitted as a new question. `%${$answer}{$key}` is not correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

## loop through all the keys in answear = { outargs => { key1, key2 }}

```
# This should remove the error of "Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden" by wrapping the hashRef in %{}
for ( keys %{$answear->{outargs}}) {
    # $_ here will be the key and if you want to access the value use $answear->{outargs}->{$_}
    print "key: $_, value: $answear->{outargs}->{$_}\n";
}
```

output:

```
key: connectionId, value: 1557666855346
```

I hope this will help you!